# Monotonic vector linear trasformed to another monotonic vector

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vectors

Let $b = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\forall i \in \left\{ 1,\ldots, n \right\}$ we have $b_i > 0$ and $\forall i \in \left\{1,\ldots,n-1 \right\}$ we have $b_i > b_{i+1}$. Let also $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$Ax = b$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is an invertible matrix. Are there known conditions that state what conditions should hold the matrix $A$ in order to preserve the monotonic behaviour of the vector $b$? I.e. is there a condition to check for $A$ to see if the $x_i > x_{i+1}$ $\forall i \in \left\{1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$? If such conditions exists but are too complicated to be expressed could a tridiagonal structure of the matrix allow to state simpler conditions?

I guess the problem could also be exposed in terms of

$$
x = Tb
$$
where $T = A^{-1}$

Comment: Were you able to get conditions for this property to hold?

Comment: I never was unfortunately

Comment: Somehow I'm unable to get references that can properly define a Monotonic Vector.

Comment: What is wrong with the definition I gave? I think it's intuitive, or do you mean a formal one from literature?

Comment: Your definition is perfect. I want to provide a formal definition and give literature reference.

Comment: My guess is since elements of a vector can be arbitrarily interchanged, any vector can become monotonic and thus there is no formal concept of monotonic vector. And the transformation may not result in a monotonic vector. I have found out Monotone Operators and Monotone Mapping. Definition for Monotone Mapping is given in [Variational Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540627722) Chapter 12. Not sure if it is relevant to your question.

Comment: Well if $A$ is diagonal with positive entries the monotonic behaviour won't change, indeed I was asking for condition / constraints on the matrix $A$ to preserve such behaviour. I came across monotone operators and I thought they might be related, but I haven't investigated this since. How come you're looking into this?

Comment: As part of my dissertation, I want to prove that the transformation  that I have derived from a Markov chain gives a vector that is monotone when the input vector is monotone. There isn't any definition I have come across where for monotone mapping in explained in simple english or by using an algebraic or numerical example. Also the only way to prove monotonicity is to use partial derivatives or to prove using the definition of monotone mapping. Sadly I lack knowledge on handling derivatives related to system of linear equations that are used in stationary probabilities of Markov chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118645/discussion-between-user8469759-and-prash).